# Universal vs Hybrid apps Xamarin.Forms Portable vs Xamarin.Forms Shared

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Can someone explain me what is the difference between templates you see in Visual studio for App development, Hybrid vs Universal,  Xamarin.Forms Portable vs Xamarin.Forms Shared.
Is the Hybird app used only for Javascript based app that can run in the browser and run on the phone browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a nice reading [here](http://hotkrossbits.com/2015/05/03/xamarin-forms-pcl-vs-shared-project/) explaining the difference among PCL vs. Shared Project.